# Online chat list

Tags: android, android-listview, gmail, chat

I had made a chat list of gmail users. What is wrong with code. When I am running this code,  this code is not showing any user name. sometimes it shows error that the content of adapter has changed, but ListView didn't receive notification.

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {

static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";
public static final String USERNAME = "user@gmail.com";
public static final String PASSWORD = "password";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> chatList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();

            } catch (XMPPException ex) {

            }

            try {
                connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                    "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);

            final Roster roster = connection.getRoster();

             Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
             for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                                .getUser());

                 Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                 map.put("USER", entry.getUser().toString());
                 map.put("STATUS", type.toString());

                     chatList.add(map);
            }
            roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {

                @Override
                public void presenceChanged(Presence arg0) {


                }

                @Override
                public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });


    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);     
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

And this is my ListAdater code

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageView imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageView(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> chats= new HashMap<String, String>();
    chats= data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(chats.get("USER"));
    if (chats.get("STATUS").equalsIgnoreCase("available"))
        thumb_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.online);
    else
        thumb_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ofline);
    return vi;
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes this code start working suddenly...

Comment: Am trying the same kind of code but am not able to add the values to map ... Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(roster_entry.getUser());
                Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                map.put("user_address", roster_entry.getUser().toString());
map shows only last value .. help me out..

Comment: I have edited the code now it will work fine. If the code will work the give reputation to this.

Comment: Thank you .. Very Much.. Up vote :)happy 100 reputations ...